# Question mark in url (Apache)

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, kohana, url-encoding

I have a problem with a question mark in url.

For example: I have the url `test.com/controller/action/part_1%3Fpart_2` (where %3F is url encoded question mark), and with this rewrite rule: `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]`, it should be passed to framework I use (Kohana) as is. At least I thought so.

The problem is that everything after the url encoded question mark is being treated as GET parameter, so Kohana receives only the `part_1` and I can see that there is an array key `part_2` in `$_GET`. I think it's web servers problem (apache 2.2).

What should I do so apache wouldn't treat url encoded question mark as a GET parameter indicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question mark is one of the [reserved characters](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#sec-2.2), used as separator between PATH and QUERY components. So, you cant use it as a part of URI path.

Comment: It can be used, if it's escaped - "If the data for a URI component would conflict with the reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before forming the URI." (from the link you gave). Also you can check here http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm about url encoding.
In my example the question mark IS escaped (url encoded).